# Ifstream and Ofstream problems

Tags: c++, iostream

Hello I am having a bit of trouble understanding Ifstream and Ofstream. I am trying to import text from a premade file called "thefile.txt" which contains:

```
Google (GOOG)
522.01 2 100
520.66 1.5 80
Apple (AAPL)
389.27 2 150
401.82 1.8 150
Microsoft (MSFT)
25.06 2.5 100
25.07 2 80
```

here is the code chunk:

```
fin.open(inputfile);
fin >> stockname1 >> buyingcost1 >> commission1 >> shares1 >> sellingcost1 >> sellingcomish1 >> sharessold1
    >> stockname2 >> buyingcost2 >> commission2 >> shares2 >> sellingcost2 >> sellingcomish2 >> sharessold2
    >> stockname3 >> buyingcost3 >> commission3 >> shares3 >> sellingcost3 >> sellingcomish3 >> sharessold3;
fin.close();
```

everything is declared correctly and i have "#"included everything that needs to be included but when I try to access the variables they are all still empty.

Comment: We need more information. Please add the variable declarations. Also you didn't check if `fin` is still `good()` (or ever was after `open()`).

Comment: Most likely is that the file doesn't exist in your working directory. A good first step is to verify that the file was successfully opened. Wrap your input in an `if (fin)` conditional, print an error message in the `else` branch.

Comment: alright is it okay to just throw the whole program in the code section?

Comment: Currently `stockname1` will read in `Google` and `buyingcost1` will try to read in `(GOOG)` because `>>` reads only one word at a time.

Comment: @HalpMehPlz No it's not OK to throw just your whole program here. You are expected to show a [minimal version](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), that reproduces the same behavior.

Comment: Also you might consider making a loop rather than hard-coding to read exactly 3 records.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For strings, `operator >>` reads word by word. You have to use [std::getline](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/) for `stockname`'s.

(I assume the input file is opened successfully)

So you do:

```
std::getline(fin, stockname1);
fin >> buyingcost1 >> commission1 >> shares1 >> sellingcost1 >> sellingcomish1 >> sharessold1;
// skip until EOL so next getline() reads the right thing
fin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
```

[Demo](http://ideone.com/5HBc2m)

Comment: How would I use that in a list like I have? Would it be std::getline(fin,stockname1);

Comment: Still not getting anything to print and the program is going into if(fin)

Answer (score 0):

I think your program fails to open the file.According to your code, I guess stockname1 is a string.If the file is successfully opened, there should be something in stockname1.To check the problem, the first step is to add if(fin) conditional and output something in the branch to debug. The mistake Anton Savin mentioned also exists.

Answer (score 0):

I speculate the issue could be "fin.open(inputfile);"
perhaps "fin.open(inputfile , ios::in);" would work?
(for input, if you also need output then use ", ios::in | ios::out", proper info on the link below)

---

another thing that could be the issue is (for example) "Google (GOOG)", since as far as I know the >> input interprets a space the same way as a new line.
As someone else mentioned, the "getline.()" reads a whole line (although into a string, as far as I know)

I personally found [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/files/) very helpful when learning basic c++ file handling.